# Zero line for primary and secondary axis - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to display 2 data on a plot, each of them is assigned on primary and secondary axis respectively.
Here are the codes

```
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(df['year'], df['present_value']/1000000, 'g-')
ax2.plot(df['year'], df['cum_pv']/1000000, 'b-')

ax1.set_xlabel('X data')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y1 data', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y2 data', color='b')

plt.show()
```

But it displays a chart with not equal zero levels, (notice how 0 on primary is on a different level from 0 on secondary axis) [image]`

How can I make the zero scale on the same level from my codes above?

Comment: set the limits to be the same (`ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `set_ylim()`-method of each axis to adjust them manually.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = [-1,2,3]
y2 = [-10,-5,10]
x = [1,2,3]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots() # opens a figure with a single axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx() # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
ax1.plot(x,y1, 'g-')
ax2.plot(x,y2, 'b-')

plt.show()
```

[image: no sync]

Here is a way, which assumes that there actually is a zero in both y-axes

```py
# range
ax1_range = ax1.get_ylim()[1] - ax1.get_ylim()[0]
fct = (0 - ax1.get_ylim()[0])/ax1_range

ax2_ylim = ax2.get_ylim()
# calculate new values for the second axis
ax2_ylim_new = (ax2_ylim[0],(0 - ax2_ylim[0]) / fct + ax2_ylim[0])
# set new limits
ax2.set_ylim( ax2_ylim_new )

plt.show()
```

[image: manual sync]

I scaled the second y-axis `ax2` so that it exhibits the `0` at the same height of the axis as the first y-axis `ax1`. This becomes more tricky if one of the axes does not contain zero (so the limits do not have a change of the sign). You could write a little function, which handles the different cases if you like to have a generic solution.